# Django Redirect to Second URL

Tags: python, django, url, redirect

I'm trying to redirect to an custom url as it's coded in the below. However there might be a broken url. Therefore, I like to redirect to an second url in case of error.

**Is there any way to redirect to an second url in case of an error?**

```
        page = self.request.POST.get('ex_page')
        return redirect(page)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "broken URL" menas that the lookup of `page` is impossible because it doesn't exist in the relevant `urls.py`, then:

```
from django.urls.exceptions import NoReverseMatch
...

try:
    destination = redirect(page)
except NoReverseMatch:
    destination = redirect('homepage')
return destination
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to check if the URL resolves and then redirect to a secondary page.

```py
page = self.request.POST.get('ex_page')

try:
  resolve(page)
  return redirect(page)
except Resolver404:
  return redirect(secondary_url)
```